# Bash Unexpected End of File Error After Installing RVM

Tags: rvm, gnupg, bash

I executed the following commands under BASH to install RVM:

```
brew install gnupg gnupg2

gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3

\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Now, when I open my terminal, I receive the following error message:

```
-bash: eval: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here is my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
eval "$(rbenv init -)i"
alias sbl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'

#changes prompt to be colorized and rearranges prompt to be "username@hotname:cwd $"
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "

#enable command line colors, and define colors for the ‘ls’ command
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad

#flags -G colorizes output, -h makes sizes human readable, and -F throws a / after a directory
alias ls='ls -GFh'


#Need to add below after 'brew install git bash-completion'
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
fi
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Can someone point out what is causing the error? I am not familiar with BASH programming. RVM is working.

Comment: What does `rbenv init -` return? (I'm assuming that's not the problem though.) Does the problem go away if you comment out that last line? Do you get the error if you run that last line yourself?

Comment: `rbenv init -` returns the following: 

`export PATH="/Users/pc3sq/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
source "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash"
rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
  typeset command
  command="$1"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval `rbenv "sh-$command" "$@"`;;
  *)
    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}`


Commenting out the last line and restarting terminal still returns the same error at line 19. When I enter the last line of my bash_profile into the terminal itself, there are no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you have a stray "i" at the end of the second line:

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)i"
```

Because of that, `eval` is trying to run a command sequence that looks something like this:

```
export PATH="/Users/pc3sq/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
# [...]
rbenv() {
    # [...]
}i
```

...and since "}i" is not a valid match for the "{" that starts the function definition, `eval` runs into the end of the "file" (actually just a string) while it's still looking for a "}" to close the function definition.